# mariadb (mysql) innodb not optimizing SELECT for partitions?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, partitioning, debugging

I have a table partitioned by on column "level" -- I have logs where level 7 is the verbose info, which is like 20x as many entries as all the other levels.

When purging old logs in level 7, it was taking quite a while. I had assumed it was just the amount of logs. (And possibly also the transaction time).

But when I compared the query-select with a clone in myisam, it seems it's ignoring the simple partition optimization it could make!

Even worse, this select optimization doesn't carry over to the `DELETE` query, as per `EXPLAIN`! It takes the partition, but won't use the `date` index!

Is this a bug, or just my lack of knowledge?

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'
innodb_version                      5.6.26-74.0
protocol_version                    10
version                             10.1.9-MariaDB-1~jessie
version_comment                     mariadb.org binary distribution
version_compile_machine             x86_64
version_compile_os                  debian-linux-gnu
version_malloc_library              system jemalloc
version_ssl_library                 OpenSSL 1.0.1t 3 May 2016
wsrep_patch_version                 wsrep_25.11
```

https://gist.github.com/avimar/16824955e21781c7e2c6594ef743bc6f

```
show create table logs_fs
CREATE TABLE `logs_fs` (
  `uuid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `hrtime` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text,
  KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (level)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = InnoDB,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = InnoDB) */
```

**My naive query: sql should know which partition!**

```
explain select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) FROM `logs_fs` WHERE `date` < date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) and level=7
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  logs_fs ALL date    NULL    NULL    NULL    1,777,576   Using where
```

**I had to specify the partition AND leave out the level=7 to get down to a lower number!**

```
explain select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) FROM `logs_fs` PARTITION (p1) WHERE `date` < date_sub(now(), interval 1 week)
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  logs_fs range   date    date    8   NULL    423,360 Using where; Using index
```

**Indeed, it works in myisam!** (Funny, it says it's querying 196k rows, but it returns the proper count of 210701 which matches innodb)

```
CREATE TABLE `logs_fs_myisam` (
  `uuid` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  `host` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `hrtime` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` text,
  KEY `uuid` (`uuid`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
/*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (level)
(PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (7) ENGINE = MyISAM,
 PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (8) ENGINE = MyISAM) */

explain select SQL_NO_CACHE count(*) FROM `logs_fs_myisam` WHERE `date` < date_sub(now(), interval 1 week) and level=7`
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  logs_fs_myisam  range   date    date    8   NULL    195,890 Using where
```

Comment: Use `explain partitions select ...` and check if your partition really isn't used, it should work correctly. The value in `rows` can just be a (wild) guess. Try to `optimize table logs_fs` (can take some time), it might give you better statistics afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

`PARTITIONing` with fewer than 10 partitions is rarely useful.

Perhaps `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(date))` would be better?  Perhaps daily partitions is best for your application.

Is your goal to purge only "level 7 AND old"?  The gets rather messy because  you would be purging only part of a partition, not being able to `DROP PARTITION`.

On the other hand, *maybe* this is a valid application for subpartitioning??  That would be exciting (to me) since I have not yet seen a use for subpartitioning.  Beware of the limitations of what you can put in the `BY` clause.

I think you would have to go with

```
 PARTITION BY RANGE(date)
     SUBPARTITION BY KEY(level)
```

And use `ALTER TABLE ... TRUNCATE PARTITION ...`  This would leave an empty partition behind, but it would be quick.  Check the ramifications of `innodb_file_per_table=1`.